# Creating a drop-down list of Dates in Google Forms from values on a Google Sheet creates list of Strings instead

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a script that allows me use data from a spreadsheet to create a dynamic drop-down list in a Google Form. The data in spreadsheet is a list of dates, but when it gets added to the drop-down list in Google Forms it becomes a string. By the time someone submits a response, the data goes to a spreadsheet and this drop-down's value gets considered as a string instead of a date, e.g. **'5/5/2018** instead of **5/5/2018**.

```
var fromRange = 'RequestDates'; //namedRange from Spreadsheet for 'From date' dropdown
var toRange = 'RequestToDates'; //namedRange from Spreadsheet for 'To date' dropdown

function updateDates(e){
  // a way to get the items from the form
  var form = FormApp.openById("10uyPYIpVtKLg5eaxIrc8di93v7NW1ZSL6gjbtQs4NvE");
  var FromList = form.getItemById(1.403587334E9).asListItem();
  var ToList = form.getItemById(4.09925665E8).asListItem();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var FormsTest = ss.getSheetByName("AppScript");

  // get the values in the first column accept header row 1
  var FromValues = FormsTest.getRange('RequestDates').getDisplayValues();
  var ToValues = FormsTest.getRange('RequestToDates').getDisplayValues(); 

  var FromNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < FromValues.length; i++) {  
    if(FromValues[i][0] != "") {
      FromNames[i] = FromValues[i][0];
    }
  }

  var ToNames = [];
  for(var y = 0; y < ToValues.length; y++) {  
    if(ToValues[y][0] != "") {
      ToNames[y] = ToValues[y][0];
    }
  }

  // populate the list
  FromList.setChoiceValues(FromNames);
  ToList.setChoiceValues(ToNames);
}
```

The list of dates from the spreadsheet gets automatically updated everyday to only allow 12 days after the current day until 180th days after the current day which means the dynamic drop down also gets updated automatically everyday. I'm very new to javascript so any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the leading single quote with a JavaScript String method like substring or slice or replace. Then use the new Date(string) constructor. It’s quite robust and probably will recognize the pattern and coerce it into a date.

Comment: For example i have my dates in range C2:C, how do I use slice or replace for the single quote to be removed?.  I tried function dateformat(e){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var FormResponse = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var dateRange = FormResponse.getRange("C2:C");
  
  dateRange.getValues().slice(0);
} but it's not working

Comment: The first value in var data=dareRange.getValues() is data[0][0] (i.e. it’s two dimensional) so it would be data[0][0].slice(1)

Comment: Sorry Im new to all this, is it supposed to look like this? 
    'dateRange.getValues().data[0][0].slice(1);'

Comment: No. I said var data=dateRange.getValues();var newstring=data[0][0].slice(1);You may have to put String() around the data element.

Comment: I now have 'function dateformat(e){
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var FormResponse = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var dateRange = FormResponse.getRange("C2:C");
  var data=dateRange.getValues().toString();
  var newstring = data[0][0].slice(1);
}', I also tried to do it without the toString() but still did'nt do anything

Comment: How about just `getValues()` instead of `getDisplayValues()` in your original script

Comment: [`Form#ListItem#setChoiceValues(values)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoiceValues(String)) requires `values` to be an array of `String`s. It should not be surprising then that your list is made of strings. If you want to use actual `Date`s, then you will have to make a [`DateItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item) for each one of them.

Comment: Hi Tehhowch, as far as i know, dateitem can only be used if the item is a calendar. If i do this, is there a way to only show calendar dates based on the data on my spreadsheet?

Comment: You do realize that you can simply change the  number format to date in destination spreadsheet itself right? Alternatively, use `onFormSubmit()` to `setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: Hi |'-'|, I'm actually trying to avoid manually changing the date format in the destination spreadsheet that's why I am trying to automate it via apps script. Also, to answer your previous comment about using getValues(), I tried it and the dropdown list will show the data from the spreadsheet as timestamp like this (GMT+8:00 mm/dd/yyyy mm:hh:ss) instead of just  (mm/dd/yyyy). And still, as what tehhowch mentioned, dropdown list item will consider/convert the data on my spreadsheet as string regardless of it's original format  by the time the user submits a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function dateformat(e){ //I presume your in a spreadsheet getting an onFormatSubmit trigger
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow(),1); 
  var data=rg.getValues(); //the plan would be to iterate over all of the rows I guess. 
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var datstr=String(data[i][0]).slice(1);
    data[i][0]=new Date(datstr);
  }
  rg.setValues(data);//This will replace the strings with the date values and you can set the format for that range anyway you wish.
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message that says "Missing ; before statement." on this line var data[i][0]=new Date(datstr);  my code looks exactly like the one that you posted so I'm not sure where I should put that missing ;

Comment: I changed the code a little. Where it says var data[i][0] just remove the var.

Comment: So I tried this again and it worked! Though i have to change the code a little: 'var rg = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow(),1)' to 'var rg = sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow()-1,1)' and 'var datstr=String(data[i][0]).slice(1);' to 'var datstr=String(data[i][0]).replace("'","");' , thanks Cooper!